# What is a transmit-only frequency?

Tags: radio-communications, aeronautical-charts, fss

[image]

I found the above in the Jeppesen *Airport Chart Legend.*

What would be an example of a transmit-only frequency? Is it related to [Flight Service Stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_service_station)? If so, how?

Where can I find an example for transmit-only frequency on a chart?

Comment: Are you talking about certain frequencies usually shared with navaids that are transmit on one frequency and receive on an other?

Comment: Maybe when the same ATC operator can use multiple frequencies, and cross-couple them (retransmit one to the other) or disconnect cross-coupling (to prevent an aircraft to RFI others). Seems to be used in [Indianapolis terminal aera](https://www.reddit.com/r/ATC/comments/2cuucj/can_atc_transmit_on_multiple_freqs_at_a_time/).

Comment: Would GUARD be an example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
([skyvector.com](https://skyvector.com/airport/RDD/Redding-Municipal-Airport)) Chart Supplement for Redding Municipal Airport.

An example of transmit-only frequency would be a VOR frequency used for a [remote communications outlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_communications_outlet) (RCO). From the example above, 108.4T is a transmit-only frequency using the voice channel of the VOR.

How to use: [How do I contact Flight Service while in flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1473)